# What does this Barbary Macaque facial expression mean?

Tags: zoology, ethology, behaviour

A girl pretended having a piece of food in her hand and pointed it to a Barbary Macaque in Gibraltar. As a response he made this facial expression to her. What does this mean?

[image: GibraltarBarbaryMacaqueExpressions]

Comment: What was the sound that it made?  Macaque vocalizations are also well studied, and it looks like it was vocalizing.

Comment: @Atl LED The macaque didn't make any sound, its lips were maybe more like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Expression_of_the_Emotions_Figure_18.png and its eyes wide open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is trying too threat.

[image]

Source:

[Individual differences in scanpaths correspond with serotonin transporter genotype and behavioral phenotype in rhesus monkeys (Macaca mulatta)](http://journal.frontiersin.org/Journal/10.3389/neuro.08.050.2009/full)

Answer (score 4):

That is a threat face.  Barbary macaque threat faces often appear with a brow raise, lowered head, and an o-shaped mouth, sometimes with and sometimes without a vocalization.  Given the context you described it is not surprising the girl received a threat.  *Based on personal research experience

Comment: It would be fantastic if you provided some references.